# Manifold Hypothesis vs. Latent Variables Assumption

Tags: machine-learning, latent-variable, manifold-learning

As I understand:

The manifold hypothesis claims that real world data, although represented in high dimension space, actually lies on a manifold in that space. I.e. that the actual data structure is of lower dimension.

The latent variable assumption is that the observed data actually comes from an hidden latent variable, most often of a lower dimension.

So I was wondering - what is exactly the difference / similarity between the two assumptions? Are they not in-fact closely related and used interchangeably? Or are there some distinct differences between the two?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: @Wicher I added more info